# Corona SDK Storyboard: how to access the associated display group from my custom callback

Tags: coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I only know basics in using storyboard. I created a scene without problem, and then I added my own callback (returned from a asynchronous http request). Therefore in my scene Lua file, I have following

```
local function httpCallback(data) 

// process data

// screen update

end
```

For "screen update", I don't have access to the associated display group, which I mean the "self.view" in the scene listeners, for example,

```
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view
end
```

How do I get access to the "self.view"? I was thinking to use a variable to track self.view, but with "asynchronous" callback, I am afraid self.view would have become nil before I find out?

What's the proper way for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your storyboard module you should have the line:

```
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
```

or something similar. This is your scene.  for the event handlers like createScene() and such they get passed "scene' as "self".   Therefore you can always (after createScene() is first called) refer to the scene's view (a display.newGroup for all intents and purposes) using the code:

```
scene.view:insert(someDisplayObject)
```

which means you can also do:

```
local group = scene.view
```

and then use the group reference if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, `scene.view` is exactly what I need. Before your answer, I was using `storyboard.getScene("scenePageView").view` instead, which I think kind of weird.